# Mongodb Nested model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My model looks like following

```
User Model
{
    UserName:'string',
    Mobile: string
}

Post Model
{
    Post:string,
    Date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    User: 'ObjectId'
}
```

While getting data How can I get result like.

```
posts=[
{Post:'abc',Date:'10/10/2016',User:{UserName:'testuser1',Mobile:'9090123456'}},
{Post:'abc',Date:'10/10/2016',User:{UserName:'testuser2',Mobile:'9090123457'}}
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add

```
User : {type : Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'User'}
```

in your Post Model

and when you query you have to do

```
db.Post.find({}).populate('User')
```